# How can I see the correct number of a particular status if the status changes from time to time (historical data)

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

How can I see the correct number of a particular status  if the status changes from time to time (historical data)

I want to get the exact number of appointments set during a particular period of time considering that their status can or cannot have changed. Thank you!

```
WITH historisation AS (SELECT created_by_name AS "Agent", t1.lead_id, t1.date_created, CASE WHEN t1.status_label='Appointment Set' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "Appointments Set"
FROM leads__opportunities t1

INNER JOIN (SELECT lead_id, MAX(date_created), date_updated FROM leads__opportunities GROUP BY 1,3) t2

ON t1.lead_id=t2.lead_id AND t1.date_created=t2.date_updated
WHERE t1.status_label='Appointment Set'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4)

SELECT "Agent", SUM("Appointments Set") AS "Total Appointments Set"
FROM historisation
WHERE date_created>=now() - INTERVAL '1 Week'
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: You r question seems to be around data structure, what you are looking for is an SCD (slowly changing dimension) which will record a history of status changes for a particular key over a period of time. this then allows you to count the status's ata particular time to identify what was active or not.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I would add a [daterange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) (or tsrange) column to the table, e.g. `valid_during`. Then you can efficiently query the correct value using `valid_during @> current_date`

Comment: kindly specify your database server using.. Is it a `SQL` of `PostgreSQL`? And kindly provide a sample data and expected output.

Comment: @VijunavVastivch I use PostgreSQL, I was finally able to solve the problem. Thank you for your comment I will add sample data and expected output next time.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for your idea! I was finally able to solve the problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It was my first question here so I wasn't sure of how to structure it but I will definitely do that next time, for now this question was solved. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @jimmy8ball Thank you very much for your comment I looked up SCD and was able to understand a lot more about this kind of situation, thanks!

Comment: @RubP no problem at all glad to be of help